# My default browser is set to Firefox but links open with Chromium

Tags: gnome3, browser, defaults

I'm using Linux Mint Debian edition and I have set Firefox as my default browser in my settings.
But HTTP links in other apps like hotot and pidgin open with Chromium!
Why is this happening is there any way to track the problem?

Comment: [This Pidgin ticket](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/12505) might provide some clues.

Comment: not just pidgin, libre office, hotot have the same problemq

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to guess the following

- all of those tools use [XdgUtils](http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/XdgUtils)
- if you type `xdg-open http://google.com` it'll open with Chromium
- and that you have [the problem described in this Ubuntu forumspost](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1715582)

So my suggested answer is:

```
$ xdg-mime default firefox.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
```

(and ditto for https)

Comment: That worked! Thanks! May I know what is the reason for my problem? is it a bug or something like thath?

Comment: Not entirely sure: I think it's that Chromium installs those scheme handlers and Firefox has no equivalent, so it's overridden.

Comment: ok thnx for the help

Comment: If you're using a debian based system and you've done this but it's still not working try running `update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`

Comment: you made my day. Had this problem since years.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

And choose Firefox as default browser.
Only after that it was working. The change:

```
xdg-mime default Firefox.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
```

didn't work itself. 
After adding both — it is working just fine.

Comment: this is only valid on Ubuntu. Other (non-Debian-based) distros have no `update-alternatives`

Answer (score 2):

```
gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/http <whatever chrome is>.desktop
gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/https <whatever chrome is>.desktop
```